# Source code for rspec "describe" method (and others)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems, dsl

I'm sauntering through Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial right now, and am finding that I'm constantly encouraged to use wonderful methods that inexplicably do amazing things. He does a generally competent job of explaining what they do, but there is no real nitty gritty of why and how they work.

Specifically, I have just been plundering the rspec gem on github searching for the source code to the "describe" method. I cannot find it. Having now read a large amount of the source code (at an apprehension rate of about 25%) searching for it, I know that once found, I will need to look at its parent classes and modules to understand a certain amount of inheritance before I can really grasp (and then never let go of) the flesh and bones of "describe".

I don't mind struggling to grasp the concept, I'm a fan of attempting to read code in new languages before I fully understand it so that I can read it again later and use the comparison of my comprehension as a gauge of my fluency. I'd just like a kicker. Either a description or a file location with maybe a little helper hint to get me started.

For example...

I found this:

```
  #     RSpec.describe "something" do # << This describe method is defined in
  #                                   # << RSpec::Core::DSL, included in the
  #                                   # << global namespace (optional)
```

and rpsec/core/dsl states:

```
# DSL defines methods to group examples, most notably `describe`,
# and exposes them as class methods of {RSpec}. They can also be
# exposed globally (on `main` and instances of `Module`) through
# the {Configuration} option `expose_dsl_globally`.
```

but then there is no "class Describe" or def "describe" or such in that file.

SO: can anyone tell me where the "describe" method is, how it works, exactly, or (if not) why I am naively searching for the wrong thing in the wrong locations?

Comment: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/339e459276a869dc9d3850fd9b25979f85e347f8/lib/rspec/core/shared_context.rb#L49-L51

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may know, there is no difference between `describe` and `context` methods and you can use them interchangably. Rspec developers could not let themselves to repeat the same code for different method names, so they moved the declaration to

```
module RSpec
  module Core
    class ExampleGroup
      def self.define_example_group_method(name, metadata={})
        # here they really define a method with given name using ruby metaprogramming
        define_singleton_method(name) do |*args, &example_group_block|
```

And call that method a bit later for all the same-functionality DSL methods:

```
define_example_group_method :example_group
define_example_group_method :describe
define_example_group_method :context
```

So in case you are looking for `describe` method source, dive into `define_example_group_method` with assumption that `name` argument equals to `describe` and `example_group_block` is your block body.

Comment: That explanation was exactly what I was missing when staring at those files for who knows how long... Going back specifically to the top link that @Jon posted below allowed me to gain some insight. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The RSpec code base is not a trivial thing to get your head round. However, these links should get you started ...

This line defines the describe keyword:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb#L246

The method above that line does the heavy lifting for you. Take your time reading it.

This part then exposes the generated method:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb#L54

Good luck!

Comment: I'd already read through both of those .rb files and flailed at them futilely. Now I have the starting point I need. The top link especially plus the description above by @twonegatives really cracked the door open for me. Thank you.